# How to check for 404 pages from other sites?

Tags: seo, domains, 404

I just caught a domain that was going to be dropped. Business very similar to mine. 
The previous site had few subpages and they were linked from outside. However it's hard now to find what all the subpages URL were.

How can I find all the previous subpages?
Wayback machine helps in part.
Search Console doesn't help I think.

How can I find the previous urls of that domain? Or at least the urls that were and still are back linked in other sites and from time to time visitors click on them and will get a 404?

Comment: "Search Console doesn't help I think." - Why do you think so? This is exactly what the 404 report in GSC should help you with. However, ideally you would need to know what content was on these pages, in order to take advantage of any existing SEO, not just the URL that is being requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said the internet archive should give you some sense with content and link.

The other option would be to use backlink checker and it should give you some details depending on the popularity of the domain.

Note: You may need to find old preferred URL version (http, https, http://www etc) when you will use the backlink checker.

Comment: What about some script or something I can put on my site. Or some internal php. Or some external service .js that will chceck all the users that arrive to a non existing page and then gives me the list so I can add those pages?

Comment: Once you will acquire the domain, you can set Google webmasters and it should give you details about any significant 404 URLs and you can also use some third party tool to get some insights. But if you wanna know prior to acquiring the domain then backlink checker is the best option.

Comment: No script is needed.  Just look in the access_log produced by you webserver.   It records the referrer there.   List all the 404 erros that have referrers out of the log.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a httpd apache server you can just refer the access logs which resulted in 404. If your logging is fine then you should be getting the request url with the request type. 
If your logging is not upto the mark then use the following log format:
`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" common`

Comment: I am using nginx